# How to solve composer dependencies for Symfony and CalendarBundle?

Tags: symfony, dependencies, composer-php, symfony-2.2

I want to use [yvoyer/CalendarBundle](https://github.com/yvoyer/CalendarBundle) on my Symfony2.2 project.

I add it to `composer.json` and run:

```
composer update star/calendar-bundle --prefer-source
```

And it returns this error:

```
$ composer update star/calendar-bundle --prefer-source
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.2.0
    - star/calendar-bundle 0.1 requires symfony/symfony 2.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.11, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.9].
    - star/calendar-bundle 0.1.1 requires symfony/symfony 2.1.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.1.0, v2.1.0-BETA1, v2.1.0-BETA2, v2.1.0-BETA3, v2.1.0-BETA4,v2.1.0-RC1, v2.1.0-RC2, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.0.10].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.0.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.0.12].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.0.13].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.0.14].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.0.15].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.0.16].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.0.17].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.0.18].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.0.19].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.0.20].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.0.21].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.0.22].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.0.23].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.0.9].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.1.0].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.1.0-BETA1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.1.0-BETA2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.1.0-BETA3].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.1.0-BETA4].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.1.0-RC1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.1.0-RC2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.1.1].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.1.10].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.1.11].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.1.2].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.1.3].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.1.4].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.1.5].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.1.6].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.1.7].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.1.8].
    - Can only install one of: symfony/symfony[v2.2.0, v2.1.9].
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony == 2.2.0.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.2.0].
    - Installation request for star/calendar-bundle 0.* -> satisfiable by star/calendar-bundle[0.1.1, 0.1].
```

What is the cause of error? I'm thinking to fork the project and change the `composer.json`. But what should I put on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the first 3 lines of the error:

```
- Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.2.0
- star/calendar-bundle 0.1 requires symfony/symfony 2.0.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.11, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.9].
- star/calendar-bundle 0.1.1 requires symfony/symfony 2.1.* -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.1.0, v2.1.0-BETA1, v2.1.0-BETA2, v2.1.0-BETA3, v2.1.0-BETA4,v2.1.0-RC1, v2.1.0-RC2, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9].
```

That first line gives us an indication that the version of the `symfony/symfony` package is wrong. The 2 lines below it gives us the reasons why it's wrong:

- version 0.1 requires Symfony 2.0.x
- version 0.1.1 requires Symfony 2.1.x

So there is no support for 2.2.x.

What you should do if you want to use this bundle in 2.2:

1. Fork the bundle and test it with sf 2.2
2. Remove all deprecated stuff and make it comptable with 2.2
3. Update `composer.json` to have something like `symfony/symfony: 2.2.*`
4. Request a PR with the changes you made, let it merge and let the author of the bundle create a new version of the bundle and use that one in your composer.json

Comment: Yup, I'm forking it. I change require symfony/symfony to 2.2.*. And also change `"doctrine/dbal" : "2.3.*"` and it works. Do you have any idea what to put on `"symfony/symfony": "2.2.*"` to support both 2.1.* and 2.2.*?

Comment: or, what's better, if 2.3 is also supported: `~2.1`